# How to set popup window position based on button position in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am adding button programatically while clicking on button I need show PopupWindow in that button position when ever orientation is changing that button position also changes..

Comment: I think RelativeLayout could help to do so, make a popup window layout and hide it, display it when click the button.

Comment: Could you plz explain how it will works - Tom

Comment: Check this answer [How to show PopupWindow at special location?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7502433/3512164)

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to tell you what I thought to make it, may not be the best solution, just a reference. All sources here are pseudo-code.

Here is the parent layout, and set button and your popup window at same position:

---

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <Button android:layout_marginTop="80dp" 
     android:layout_marginLeft="80dp" >

  </Button>

  <com.yourdomain.android.PopupWindow 
      android:layout_marginTop="80dp" 
      android:layout_marginLeft="80dp" 
      android:visibility="GONE">
  </com.yourdomain.android.PopupWindow> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the layout of your popup window:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible" >


</LinearLayout>
```

Here you can create a class to bind to this layout, so its your custom component:

```
public class PopupWindow extends LinearLayout {

    protected Context _context = null;

    public PopupWindow (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        _context = context;
        setupView(context);
    }

    public PopupWindow (Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        _context = context;
        setupView(context);
    }

        public void setupView (Context context)
        {
           // here to initialize all children views in this layout
        }

        public void show ()
        {
            this.setVisibility (LinearLayout.Visible);
        }

        public void hide ()
        {
            this.setVisibility (LinearLayout.GONE);
        }

}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for giving your answer-Tom