# I need to display view like below

Tags: android

I have a list view with header when I am tapping the list view headers. I need to show view like this and one more condition is list view columns are dynamic, so when I am tapping the listview header I need to show up like this please see the below images.

When I am tapping on name need to show the ascending and descending view the same, view need to show when tap on level r pv or rank also.

[image]

Comment: can't understand your requirement very well.

Comment: I didnot get any dea on this one

Comment: In listview when i click on any listview header I need to show up the ascending and descending view like above image

Answer (score 0):

You can use a visibility toggle function to show or hide controls when they are clicked.

Answer (score 0):

as u said you dont have any idea then i can help you to make some starting idea.

**1)** get you all values in model array. here **model array** is a array with multiple array. you can find it on google.

**2)** use this array on your adapter then set this adapter on your listview.

**3)** now for you headers, take button above listview and perform popup on you buttons with you 2 options

**4)** now on your condition sort the model array and use it in adapter and thn set adapter to your listview.

i hope it will help you and you can start with this idea.

**another idea for header**
in your custum listview's getview take condition on position = 0 then find your header button and perform Onclick

Comment: Its good idea and thank you for your help but how can display popup like ascending and descending view when i click on reaming columns also when i cllick on it

Comment: But this popup is showing middle of the view but i dont want to do like this  i need to display exactly top of the button

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385758/how-to-set-popup-window-position-based-on-button-position-in-android .. see this