# Get The Measures of Popup Window

Tags: android, popupwindow, measurement

I already set up the pop up window, but i want to center it below the button (View v), that needs to be clicked to open it:

```
public void showPopup(Context c, View v){
    int[] location = new int[2];
    v.getLocationOnScreen(location);

    ViewGroup base = (ViewGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.pup_pattern);  
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View pupLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linearlayout_popup, base);

    final PopupWindow pup = new PopupWindow(pupLayout, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    int x = location[0] - (int) ((pupLayout.getWidth() - v.getWidth()) / 2 ); // --> pupLayout.getWidth() gives back -2?
    int y = location[1] + v.getHeight() + 10;

    pup.setFocusable(true);
    pup.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, x, y);
}
```

Has anybody an idea to get measures?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You won't get the height or width of the view, which hasn't been drawn on the screen.

`pupLayout.getWidth()` // this will give you 0

You need to get the width like this

```
int width = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec. UNSPECIFIED);
```

Use it like this

```
View pupLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linearlayout_popup, base);
pupLayout.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

int x = location[0] - (int) ((pupLayout.getMeasuredWidth() - v.getWidth()) / 2 );
```

Comment: how do i calculate y here?

Comment: @SanketPatel it depends if you want it above or below.
If below just ```anchor.bottom```

if above:  ```-anchor.height - pupLayout.measuredHeight```

Comment: what is v? what is location?

Answer (score -4):

Another way:

```
/**
 * @return Point object which:<br>
 * point.x : contains width<br>
 * point.y : contains height
 */
public static Point getViewSize(View view) {
    Point size = new Point();
    view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            size.set(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
        }
    });
    return size;
}
```