# How to adjust popup menu when pop outside container

Tags: android, popup, android-popupwindow

I am using a custom popup menu that pops inside a `RecycleView` container.

When the view touched is the on at the bottom, the popup menu hides the controls bellow the `RecycleView`.

I want to adjust the popup position in this case, bringing the popup up the exact distance needed **so the menu keeps inside the container**.

This should be easy, but i am having difficulties getting the coordinates and applying the calculations from inside the `Adapter` that deals with clicks on items.

Here is what i managed so far:

```
void show(FragmentActivity activity, View touchedView, DataItem item) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_menu, null);

        PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                popupView,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

        bind(popupWindow, popupView, item);

        //draws the menu perfectly bellow the touched element,but doesn't take in account the parent view area
        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(touchView);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out. 2 Things were on the way and are explained in comments.

```
void show(FragmentActivity activity, View touchView, IDataItem dataItem) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_menu, null);

        PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                popupView,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

        bind(popupWindow, popupView, dataItem);

        //1º problem: View item is inside ViewHolder.Item, so container is 2 levels up and touched item one level up.
        View container = (View) touchView.getParent().getParent();
        View item = (View) touchView.getParent();

        int containerHeight = container.getHeight();

        //2º problem: to get size before the popup view is displayed:  ref:https://stackoverflow.com/a/15862282/2700303
        popupView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

        int yOff=0;

        //if popup view will draw pass the bottom, get the amount needed to adjust the y coordinate
        if (ContainerHeight < item.getHeight() + item.getTop() + popupView.getMeasuredHeight())
            yOff = ContainerHeight- (item.getTop() + item.getHeight() + popupView.getMeasuredHeight());

        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(touchView,0,yOff);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
private void showPopupMenu(final View view, final int position) {
    // inflate menu
    final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), view);
    popup.setGravity(Gravity.END);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

    final EditText editText = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.input_text);
                    // setup a dialog window
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
```

And here is the outcome:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but the question is how to force the menu to keep inside the container. I don't see how you response attends to that.