# PopupWindow being cutoff towards bottom of screen

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

PopupWindow inflates fine until it is near bottom of screen it's being cut off. Anyone know how I can it inflate upwards when it's towards bottom of screen?

[image]

```
public SelectBucketMenu(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.mContext = context;

        setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        setOutsideTouchable(true);
        setFocusable(true);
        //Need set windowlayout for API 19 otherwise window won't appear
        setWindowLayoutMode(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        setupView();
    }

    private void setupView(){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                .inflate(R.layout.popupmenu_selectbucket, null);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        setContentView(view);
    }
```

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Measuring the view and then setting the height fixed my issue.

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.popupmenu_addphotos, null);
```

```
view.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
setWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
setHeight(view.getMeasuredHeight());
```

Comment: Does it work on API 19? I tested it but it didn't work. I mean popup didn't appear.

Comment: yeah it works on my api 19 real device. Did you place it before ```setContentView(view);```?

Comment: I did it before `setContentView(view);` but it still doesn't work. I tested on Emulator. Could you please share your code completely?

Comment: I found the problem. I don't know why `view.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);` doesn't work for me even on API 29 but `int spec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec. UNSPECIFIED);
    view.measure(spec, spec);` works well.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I solved in *Kotlin*

```
    val view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_certificate_context_menu,null)
    val spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
    view.measure(spec, spec)
    val popupWindow = PopupWindow(view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true)

    popupWindow.height = view.measuredHeight
    popupWindow.elevation = 3.pxF

    iv_menu.setOnClickListener {
        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(it)
       
    }
```

Comment: This is the way. setWindowLayoutMode() is deprecated and didn't even work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the folowing line

```
setWindowLayoutMode(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

with

```
setWindowLayoutMode(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0);
```

and set the Popup height by calling `setHeight` method.

The final code is as below:

```
public SelectBucketMenu(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.mContext = context;

    setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    setOutsideTouchable(true);
    setFocusable(true);
    //Need set windowlayout for API 19 otherwise window won't appear
    setWindowLayoutMode(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0);
    setHeight((int)mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.bucket_menu_height));
    setupView();
}
```

**Update**  
If you need to calculate popup height at runtime, you can find the idea in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15862282/1162154). Then the final code could be like below:

```
public SelectBucketMenu(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.mContext = context;

    setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    setOutsideTouchable(true);
    setFocusable(true);
    //Need set windowlayout for API 19 otherwise window won't appear
    setWindowLayoutMode(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0);

    setupView();
}

private void setupView(){
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                .inflate(R.layout.popupmenu_selectbucket, null);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    setContentView(view);

    int spec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec. UNSPECIFIED);
    view.measure(spec, spec);
    setHeight(view.getMeasuredHeight());
}
```

**Update 2** 
The following code is useless, you can remove it.

```
setWindowLayoutMode(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0);
```

Comment: Tried it, still being clipped towards bottom of screen https://i.imgur.com/iYH2ddO.png

Comment: Is `nav_header_height` the height of your popup window?

Comment: Whats the way to get the height of ```view``` instead of using a defined dimension height? ```View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                .inflate(R.layout.popupmenu_addphotos, null);```

Comment: the way I used below doesn't need this extra line to also work on API 19. ```setWindowLayoutMode(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0);``` but I'll give you the bounty