# PopupWindow showAtLocation not working well

Tags: android, popupwindow

I using the code below to show a `PopupWindow` but it not work well.

```
View view = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();    
popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);
```

result in Custom Phone API 25 (it work well)
[image]

```
 popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 30);
```

result in Custom Phone API 25 (`PopupWindow` is as same as **set y=0** even we set it = 30)
[image]

```
 popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 60);
```

result in Custom Phone API 25 (`PopupWindow` have margin top)
[image]

```
 popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 60);
```

result in **Google Nexus 5 API 21** (`PopupWindow` above status bar)
[image]

I want to show a `PopupWindow` below status bar `20dp` in all devices. Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Comment: You can display your popupwindow under one predefined view (Set that view visibility to invisible) . for the reference refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7502433/1848157

Comment: rather than set hard code value of #y  , you can calculate exact location of that predefined view.

Comment: @Radhey thank you so much. Using `predefined view` is a correct way, but Unfortunately, I am using this `PopupWindow` is many screen (activity) so I need to define many `predefined view`. Any suggestion?

Comment: you can calculate statusbar height programmatically and set #y accordingly.

Comment: Are you using toolbar?