# In which dimension are x/y offsets specified in showAtLocation() in PopupWindow?

Tags: android, dimension, android-popupwindow

## I'm not sure if x and y parameters should be pixels of DensityIndependentPixels.

I've tried to get this information from Android's documentation but there's no answer: 
[image: showAtLocation docs]

**After digging deeper I've only got more questions:**

The `WindowManager.LayoutParams` docs contains more explaination about x and y:
[image: WindowManager.LayoutParams documantation]
yet still not the one that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X/Y in layout params use pixels as their unit. You can take a look at this [How to show PopupWindow at special location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450959/how-to-show-popupwindow-at-special-location) for more information on how-to.

Extra: you can also convert this value with

```
float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
float px = someDpValue * density;
float dp = somePxValue / density;
```

Extra 2: you can also get width/height of the screen

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();    
float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
```