# How to show popup above a specific button in android

Tags: android

I have to show a popup like this above a button

[image]

How I can show it? I have been looking into it but still unable to find any way to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Computes the coordinates of button on the screen.
2. Create custom layout above using [PopupWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow)

> ```
> popupWindow.showAtLocation(button, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
> ```

You can refer the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450959/how-to-show-popupwindow-at-special-location)